# Country State Drop Down

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to Ajax and PHP and am encountering problems with a dynamic drop down of country and states. **Although I have checked whole lot of answers in stackOverflow** but I am not able to get a clear picture as to how we should successfully code to get the desired results.

`country.php`

```
<form method="post">

<select id="cont">
<option>Select</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","countries");
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from countries");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
    echo "<option class='con' value=".$row['id'] .">".$row['name']."</option>"; 
}
?>
</select>

<div id="states">
<select>
<option>Select</option>
</select>
</div>

</form>
```

`ajax file`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cont").change(function(){
        var c=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"country_back.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{id:c},
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg){
                ("#states").html(strMsg);
                }

            })

        })

    })
```

`country_back.php`[to fetch states data]

```
<?php
$con_id=$_POST['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","countries");
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from states where country_id='$con' ");
echo "<select>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['name']."</option>"; 
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal Getting no results in the states drop-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cont").change(function(){
        var c=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"country_back.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{id:c},
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(strMsg){
                alert(strMsg);
                $("#states").html(strMsg);
                }

            })

        })

    })
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?php
 $con_id=$_POST['id'];
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","countries");
 $data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from states where country_id='$con_id' ");  //You should use $con_id
 echo "<select>";
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
   {
     echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</option>"; 
   }
 echo "</select>";

  ?>
```

Do the changes

Comment: Say some thing about your code how it works and how it address op problem .

Comment: Yes, thats the ajax part but would you mind telling me what changes have you made to the code because it seems almost the same.

Comment: In success function, You have to write like  `$("#states").html(strMsg);`

Comment: Add alert(strMsg); to check

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal Thanks correction done but it is still showing an error. : `"Catchable fatal Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"`  `Error in country_back.php`.

Comment: this is wrong and i dont understand why it has upvote the element with ID state is not a select but a div

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe Please check the PHP Code and let me know the output which you are getting

Comment: @guradio she pointed out that I was missing a `$` inside of the success function.

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal tried your PHP code but it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @guradio tried the code you gave but it isn't giving no results, please put up the corrected code in the answers section. It would be a great help.

Comment: `$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from states where country_id='$con_id' ");` You should use $con_id

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal Thanks a lot, it works now, made a few silly mistakes but you have been such a huge help. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!